# Update Project Configuration excludes all files from src/main/resources

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am using STS version 2.8.1 which includes the m2e plugin version 1.1.

My problem is that occasionally I will see the following error in the Problems tab:

> Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml

The resolution for this involves selecting the Update Project Configuration menu item from m2e, and the error disappears.

However, I then notice that the Java build path in Eclipse has excluded all files from the src/main/resources directory and I have to manually remove this filter each time.

Is this a problem with my pom.xml, or with the m2e plugin?

My effective pom contain the following:

```
<sourceDirectory>myProject\src\main\java
</sourceDirectory>
<scriptSourceDirectory>myProject\src\main\scripts
</scriptSourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>myProject\src\test\java
</testSourceDirectory>
<outputDirectory>myProject\target\classes
</outputDirectory>
<testOutputDirectory>myProject\target\test-classes
</testOutputDirectory>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>myProject\src\main\resources
        </directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>myProject\src\test\resources
        </directory>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: I was creating a runnable jar and hit the same issue. The default POM when I created it via eclipse added an exclusion of \*\*/\*.java but I still ended up with an exclusion of ** in the Eclipse project. I'm not building the jar via Maven, just using it to manage dependencies. So for me I just removed the resources spec from Maven and added back the resources to the Eclipse project. You have to add it back, else it seems to know it's added by Maven and removes even the corrected entry